# Javascript: How to print a value from a $_SESSION array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session, persistence

Is there a way to have javascript create php code, to be executed when it runs on the php page? I'm trying to set the value of an input to , where div_id is a js variable, and inputs is a 2D associative array.

The problem is that it literally sets the value to "" instead of the value of the floor_type field. Everything else seems to work.

```
inputs_div.innerHTML += `<div id="`+div_id+`" class="dynamic_div">
                        <ul class="dynamic_ul">
                        <li><input type="text" onblur="$('.save').click();" placeholder="Flooring Type: Wood Floor, Tile, etc." name="inputs[`+div_id+`][floor_type]" maxlength="255" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['inputs']['`+div_id+`']['floor_type']; ?>"></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
```

I'm creating some html inputs dynamically with javascript, but I'm looking for a way to prevent them from getting cleared if the page is refreshed. Maybe there is a simpler way to make the inputs stay there?

My idea was to use ajax to run some php code from the onblur event of each input element, which saves the inputs[][] array into the session, so it doesn't get lost when refreshing the page.

Comment: PHP execute first and js after. in your code php need `div_id` which is causing problem

Comment: You can't print session in javascript Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362417/is-it-possible-to-read-a-php-session-using-javascript]

Comment: You cannot use javascript variables into php

Comment: use session storage to persist data in a window http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/local-storage.html#local-storage-vs-session-storage

Answer (score 1):

Use a hidden field to store $_SESSION[] value and then on document ready get the value of hidden field and set to the javascript variable.

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="<? php echo $_SESSION['inputs'] ?>" />


$(document).ready(function()
{    var session_value = $('#hdn').attr('value');    // now use session_value variable when set the innerhtml of inputs_div });
```

Comment: hmm, the value of hdn end up being just "array", not an actual array. inputs is a 2D associative array. So I need to find a way to copy it from the session to a js array

Comment: Maybe i can save the inputs array into a cookie, or sessionstorage. But then i'm not sure what to put into the onblur event of each input

Comment: You can use Ajax on document.ready() to make a call to a php page and get Session array value in its response. In success callback function you can assign response data to a javascript variable.